# List inside dictionary

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

[image]

I am unable to get the last 3 digits of the id number.

```
from datetime import datetime
def days_to_birthday(date): 
    datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
    date = datetime_object.date()
    num_days = date.timetuple().tm_yday
return num_days
fo = open("Data.txt", 'r') # File containg data
content = [i.rsplit() for i in fo.readlines()]
names = [content[i][0] for i in range(len(content))]
dates = [content[i][1] for i in range(len(content))]
gender = [content[i][2] for i in range(len(content))]
id_numbers = []
mydict = dict(zip(dates, gender))

for i in mydict:
    x = days_to_birthday(i)
    if mydict.get(i) == "F":x += 500
    x = str(x)
    if len(x) < 3:x = x.zfill(3)
    i = i.split('-')
    out = i[0] + x
    id_numbers.append(out)
for i in range(len(names)):
    print(f"{names[i]} {id_numbers[i]}" )
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). Maybe this isn't homework per se, but a lot of the same ideas apply. See also [ask]. You can [edit] if needed.

Comment: Hi, can you please post the content of the Data.txt file? Makes it easier to reproduce

Answer (score 0):

Running your code would raise `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`.

Because Python is a whitespace sensitive language, `return num_days` must be further indented so it applies within the `days_to_birthday` function.